# Why some performace fields from google ads api can't be together?

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api

[Ad Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/ad-performance-report#conversioncategoryname) states that some fields are not compatible with the some fields such as ConversionCategoryName. It can't be together impressions, clicks, cost... etc.

However They can be show together in the same table on Google ads platform.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not always possible to compare results of the API and results of the web application.  Googles web applications have different permissions then they give to developers.

If you are seeing compatible with the some fields such then you cant use that in the API there is no work around for that.